# CAML Query and statement not working

Tags: caml, query

I've been working on this query for a while now and I can't get it to return any rows. It was working before I added in the content between  and added the and statement.

```
 camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='StartDate'  Ascending='False'/></OrderBy><GroupBy>" + 
 "<FieldRef Name='SortOrder'/></GroupBy>" +
 "<Where>" +
 "<Eq>" +
 "<FieldRef Name='DisplayGroup' />" + 
 "<Value Type='Text'>Home</Value> " +
 "</Eq>" +
 "<And>" +
 "<Leq>" +
 "<FieldRef Name='StartDate' />" +
 "<Value Type='DateTime'>" +
 "<Today />" +
 "</Value>" +
 "</Leq>" +
 "</And>" +
 "</Where>" +
 "</Query>" +
 "</View>");
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, `<And>` should contain two conditions in it.. `<Eq>` and `<Leq>` both should appear within the `<And>`

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='StartDate'  Ascending='False'/></OrderBy><GroupBy>" + 
 "<FieldRef Name='SortOrder'/></GroupBy>" +
 "<Where>" +
 "<And>" +
    "<Eq>" +
       "<FieldRef Name='DisplayGroup' />" + 
       "<Value Type='Text'>Home</Value> " +
    "</Eq>" +
    "<Leq>" +
       "<FieldRef Name='StartDate' />" +
       "<Value Type='DateTime'>" +
          "<Today />" +
       "</Value>" +
    "</Leq>" +
 "</And>" +
 "</Where>" +
 "</Query>" +
 "</View>");
```